# What is the name and notation given to the inverse of the inertial resistivity $\beta$ (aka non-Darcy factor or Forchhiemer factor)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, notation, porous-media

The *viscous resistivity* $\alpha$ is the reciprocal of *permeability* $k$. That is, $\alpha=1/k$.

Considering the 1D isotropic non-Darcy equation,
$$\tag{1} -\frac{dp}{dx}=\alpha \mu  q+ \beta \rho q^2,$$

we see we have the *inertial resistivity* $\beta$ in the second term on the RHS. The equation is often written in terms of permeability like so,
$$\tag{2} -\frac{dp}{dx}=k^{-1} \mu  q+ \beta \rho q^2,$$
which, instead of keeping the congruent pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ as in (1), it uses the non-congruent pair $(k, \beta)$.

This has me wondering, what symbol and name is given to the reciprocal of *inertial resistivity* $\beta$? If there is not one, what symbol and name would you use, and why?